# How am I able to extract the value of a variable stored inside another variable?

Tags: autohotkey

```
text = "This is a textline"
PlaceHolder = "text"
```

So I want to get the value of text returned through Placeholder. But no matter what I try, it'll always return me the literal string "text". The problem is that I don't know which variable I'm going to need beforehand. So PlaceHolder can have the name of any number of variables inside the script. This allows me to know which variable I'm going to need. But it's not very helpfull if I can only use it as a literal string.

I've tried:

`% PlaceHolder` - returns text
`%PlaceHolder%` - returns text
`:= PlaceHolder` - returns text

**Explanation of what I'm doing**
I have a lot of DropDownLists inside a GUI. All of them are hidden except one. The one that is visible will show one of the others depending on which selection is made. So I have no way of knowing which DropDownList will become visible. But I do need the value of that DropDownList.

Therefor the value of the first selection ALWAYS matches the variable name of the DropDownList that becomes visible. However, this is stored as a literal string. So even though I now have the name of the variable I need, I can't access its value. Hope this all makes a little sense.

Comment: My answer shows you how print the value of a variable that is stored as a literal string. `"text"` is a string, do some replacement to remove the `""`, and print the variable.

Comment: @2501 Thanks. I'm working on it to see if I can get it to work. Will ofc accept your answer asap :)

Comment: @2501 Ok I'm still wrapping my head around it, but your magic works. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable PlaceHolder is containing the value `"text"`, but the name of the variable `text` is without the quotation marks. So make sure variable `PlaceHolder` holds the exact name of the variable or remove the quotation marks:

```
StringReplace, PlaceHolder2 , PlaceHolder , `" , , A
```

Then assign this variable enclosing it with percent signs to a new variable:

```
Out := %PlaceHolder2%
Msgbox, %Out%
```

Or simply do:

```
PlaceHolder := text ; note the absence of quotation marks
Msgbox, %Placeholder%
```

This is identical to:

```
PlaceHolder = %text%
Msgbox, %Placeholder%
```

Comment: Sorry I think I should've made it more clear. The quotation marks aren't there. I only put them here to show it's a literal string. The second solution won't work for me, because I have no idea which variable name is going to end up inside PlaceHolder. So I can't hardcode it. Let me edit my question to make it more clear about what I'm doing.

Comment: @icecub In that case you will have extract every individual word that might represent a variable from the text and do the substitution I have shown..